# How do I delete entries from one column if they appear in another?

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell

Two columns: Column A contains a complete list of available journal titles; Column B contains the ones to which my library already subscribes.

Is it possible to delete entries from Column A if they also appear in Column B?

In other words, I want to 'dovetail' two columns so that no entry is represented in both columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADO for database-type actions, for example:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim i As Integer

''http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246335

strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

''Note HDR=No, so F1,F2 etc is used for column names
''If HDR=Yes, the names in the first row of the range
''can be used.
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT F1 FROM [Sheet9$] WHERE F2 Is Null OR UCase(F2)<>UCase(F1)"

rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3

Worksheets("Sheet10").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Answer (score 0):

This may answer your question [compare two columns](http://www.computing.net/answers/office/compare-two-columns-in-excel/7968.html)

Comment: Thank you! I ran that as a VB Macro and it seems to have worked.