# Comparing two documents

Tags: regex, excel, list, csv

I have two very large lists. They both were originally in excel, but the larger one is a list of emails (about 160,000) of them with other information like their name and address etc. And the smaller one is a list of just 18,000 emails.

**My question is what would be the easiest way to get rid of all 18,000 rows from the first document that contain the email addresses from the second?**

I was thinking regex or maybe there is another application I can use? I have tried searching online but it seems like there isn't much specific to this. I also tried notepad++ but it freezes when I try to compare these large files.

-Thank You in Advance!!

Comment: Are you familiar with programming in any programming languages? If so, can you post more details about the structure and formatting of two files?

Comment: in the 160,000 list, are the e-mail address in one column? If so, you can place both lists in Excel, and use `vlookup` (this assumes e-mail addresses are going to be an exact match) to find the 18,000 mails that are duplicates and then use `AutoFilter` and `Sort` to delete them out.

Comment: A regex based solution, if at all feasible, is likely to be quite inefficient for your purposes.

Comment: If you know a little programming, you may write a script yourself. In PHP, you can use functions like `array_diff` or `array_intersect` to compare two arrays of addresses.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945776/in-a-spreadsheet-how-do-i-delete-entries-from-one-column-if-they-appear-in-anot.

Comment: Unix: `fgrep -vf doc2.txt doc1.txt >remainder.txt`

Comment: I agree with Scott Holtzman. Assuming they are formatted as csv's you can just open them in excel and use functions like vlookup, autofilter, and/or sort to compare the lists and filter them out. One thing to note is that if you have excel 2003 it has a limit of just over 65,000 rows so you would only want to use this method if you have excel 2007 or later.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry I forgot to mention what languages I am familiar with :/ Still new to posting here. I am good with C++, C, Java, Javascript, Php, a little bit of python and ruby, but basically ok with everything. It looks like the excel option is the best bet.

Comment: Definitely use Excel. This is like 30 seconds in Excel.

Comment: Scott, can you expand on this method a little bit? Possibly in an answer so I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I read a forum post at : [Here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/702406-compare-two-columns-delete-duplicates-from-just-one-column.html)

=MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$3,0)>0

Column B would be the large list, with the 160,000 inputs and column A was my list of things I needed to delete of 18,000.

I used this to match everything, and in a separate column pasted this formula. It would print out either an error or TRUE. If the data was in both columns it printed out true.

Then because I suck with excel, I threw this text into Notepad++ and searched for all lines that contained TRUE (match case, because in my case some of the data had the word true in it without caps.) I marked those lines, then under search, bookmarks, I removed all lines with bookmarks. Pasted that back into excel and voila.

I would like to thank you guys for helping and pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  One way I would tackle this is making a C++ program [you could extrapolate the idea to the language of your choice; You never mentioned which languages you were proficient in] that read each item of the smaller file into a vector of strings.  First, of course, use Excel to save the files as CSV instead of XLS or XLSX, which will comma-separate the values so you can work with them easier.  For the larger list, "Save As" a copy of just email addresses, deleting the other rows for now.

Then, you could open the larger list and use a nested loop to check if you should output to an output file.  Something like:

```
bool foundMatch=false;
for(int y=0;y<LargeListVector.size();y++) {
    for(int x=0;x<SmallListVector.size();x++) {
        if(SmallListVector[x]==LargeListVector[y]) foundMatch=true;
    }
    if(!foundMatch) OutputVector.append(LargeListVector[y]);
    foundMatch=false;
}
```

That might be partially pseudo-code, but do you get the idea?

Comment: Thank you! I am proficient in C++ so I will give this a shot when I get home (no compilers at work to work with)